# Bokeh - LabelSet - Ignore NaN Values

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm was assigning labels to all my points in a Bokeh visualization.

However, assigning labels to every point makes things too crowded. There are 100 or more points.

So I created a new column in my pandas df where I only have a label value for a random set of 10 rows. The other rows have NaN values.

Is there a way to have Bokeh ignore the NaN values and not create a label for them?

```
labels = LabelSet(x='myDateColumn', y='myNumericColumn', text='columnWithOnly10RowsHavingTextValue', level='glyph',
          x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=source, render_mode='canvas')

p.add_layout(labels)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a new dataframe for the labels and drop the rows with NaN values, convert this to a ColumnDataSource and use this as source for your labels.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p.circle(x='myDateColumn', y='myNumericColumn', source=source)

dfNoNaN = df.dropna()
noNaNsource = ColumnDataSource(dfNoNaN)
labels = LabelSet(x='myDateColumn', y='myNumericColumn', text='columnWithOnly10RowsHavingTextValue', level='glyph',
          x_offset=5, y_offset=5, source=noNaNsource, render_mode='canvas')

p.add_layout(labels)
```

Comment: Good answer, would be better with a corresponding piece of code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked exactly as you described. The only problem I'm having now is that some of my labels are overlapping, particularly if a bunch end up being in one area of the graph. The offset values cause the labels to be offset from the point, but not to not overlap each other. Any suggestions here?

Comment: You could try to compute the distance between datapoints and only show the labels of datapoints that have the most distance between them. Another option would be to use the hover tool to show the name in there or assign a color/shape to your datapoints that corresponds to a category in your data.